# Why my javascript code not work in html code?

Tags: javascript, html

Why my javascript code not work in html code ?

```html
<img class="transparent" alt="<script type="text/javascript">
var IntNum = 0
if( IntNum == 1 ){
    document.writeln("yes")
    }else{
        document.writeln("no")
        }
</script>" title="<script type="text/javascript">
var IntNum = 1
if( IntNum == 1 ){
    document.writeln("yes")
    }else{
        document.writeln("no")
        }
</script>" src="http://ecample.com/images/1.png" width="16" height="16">
```

thank all of anyone help in this site .

Comment: JS in `alt` tag? That's not how it works!

Comment: `It doesn't work` is never a good description for a problem. What does it do ? What did you expect ? What do you want to do with this code ?

Comment: Just looking at that hurts my eyes,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you can't start a tag within the opening tag of another tag.

Instead, you'll need to use a script tag and have it output the entire `img` tag, not just one attribute of it:

```
<script>
if (condition) {
    document.write('<img with one thing in it...>');
} else {
    document.write('<img with another thing in it...>');
}
</script>
```

*(Note that there's no reason to put `type` on `script` tags if the content is JavaScript, it's just page bloat; JavaScript is the default.)*

Separately, the code itself makes no sense. You have

```
var IntNum = 0
if (IntNum == 1) {
    document.writeln("yes")
} else {
    document.writeln("no")
}
```

The condition will never be true. Similarly, you then have

```
var IntNum = 1
if (IntNum == 1) {
    document.writeln("yes")
} else {
    document.writeln("no")
}
```

*That* condition will never be false.

Comment: your answer in very very very nice . thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's not absolutely how to use js my friend.

Browser will only read the script as alt and title attribute, and will not be executed as script.

Base on your code what you may trying to achieve could be something like this:

```
<img class="transparent" id="img-id" src="http://ecample.com/images/1.png" width="16" height="16">

<script>
    var image=document.getElementById('img-id');
    var IntNum = 0
    if( IntNum == 1 ){
        image.alt="yes";
        image.title="yes";
    }else{
        image.alt="no";
        image.title="no";
    }
</script>
```

But I don't know where you are getting the value of your IntNum, and it will constantly be 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code is supposed to be its own standalone element, not something embedded in an `alt` or `title` attribute.

If you want to change the `alt` or `title` attributes with Javascript code, you'll need to properly specify the code *outside* of the other tags and then have it manipulate the DOM, searching for and changing the relevant attributes, such as:

```
<html><head><script>
    function fn() {
        document.title = "Changed title";
    }
</script></head><body>
    <a href="javascript:fn()">Click here</a>
</body></html>
```